# How can I find a value is none in an object and delete the key and value with Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an object and the I want to find the value is `None`.
And the next step I want to delete the key.
I try this way:

```
>>> obj = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': None, 'e': '4', 'f': None }
>>> keys = list(obj.keys())
>>> for key in keys:
...     if obj[key] == None:
...         obj.pop(key, None)
>>> obj
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'e': '4'}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is wrong with this way?

Comment: @ScottHunter I just want to find a better way to do this

Comment: Note that `keys = list(obj)` saves you an attribute lookup and the creation of a dict view for the keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
obj = {k: v for k, v in obj.items() if v is not None}
```

If you don't want to replace the dictionary wholesale (because perhaps you have other references to it), then your approach is sound, but can be made a little more efficient still by avoiding calling `.keys()`, and using `del` instead of `dict.pop()`:

```
for key in list(obj):
    if obj[key] is None:
        del obj[key]
```

Testing for `None` should always be done with `is`; it's a singleton object.